# Multiple NSManagedObjectContext or Pass it around?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data

So I've gotten into a situation where for some reason I have data I'm saving but it doesn't fully save until I terminate the application. The details don't exactly matter but in looking through my code I discovered the following:

In My App Delegate I instantiate

- NSManagedObjectContext
- NSManagedObjectModel
- NSPersistentStoreCoordinator

I have a background thread that does a good deal of the data handling and saving - and in this thread I create a second managedObjectContext with this init call:

```
- (void)initCoreDataWithNSPersistentStoreCoordinator:(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)storeCoordinator andLocationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager {
    if (!managedObjectContext) {

        if (storeCoordinator != nil) {
            managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
            [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:storeCoordinator];
        }

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Dual Init attempted!!");
    }

    if (manager != nil) {
        [self setLocationManager:manager];
    }

    /* Setup a Notification Handler now that COREData is initialized */
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(saveContext:)
                                                 name:@"saveContext"
                                               object:nil];
}
```

Everywhere else in my code (where I'm not seeing save problems) I'm actually passing around the original context with prepareForSegue methods similar to this:

```
// Pass on managedObjectContext
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    // If the destination VC is able to take teh setManagedObjectContext method the current objectContext will be passed along.
    if ([segue.destinationViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setManagedObjectContext:)]) {
        [segue.destinationViewController performSelector:@selector(setManagedObjectContext:)
                                              withObject:_managedObjectContext];
    } else {

        NSLog(@"Segue to controller [%@] that does not support passing managedObjectContext", [segue destinationViewController]);
    }
}
```

Is one of the approaches "better" than the other?  I'm guessing the dual contexts are responsible for my impartial data refresh but I'm not really sure.  But the real question is one of these approaches "preferred" by apple and if so which.  Additionally what are the pitfalls I need to watch for in either case.

Thanks!

Comment: Not better - appropriate for situation. The main context is for use on the main thread. You need a different context for use on background threads. Is the above `[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init]` your actual code? And are you sure you only have one background thread?

Comment: Is there a downfall to sharing the same context across threads?

Comment: Yes, it won't work properly...

Comment: You cannot use one context across threads, it violates Apple's rule on thread confinement for Core Data contexts.  I would suggest searching on here or on Apple's documentation about Core Data and threading.  The basic rule is: one context per thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing the main managed object context around between your view controllers is the correct thing to do because they are all running on the main thread.

This issue is probably with your background thread managed object context. You should have a different context for this as it is important that all updates to a context are made on the correct thread (queue), but if you have multiple background threads then your current code will cause them to share the context and you will see issues.

Look at creating a different context for each background thread.

Comment: So I passed the "main" context to my background thread and now all the issues went away -> but if you say I'm doing this wrong what is the correct way to force a synchronization?

Comment: Correct is a different MOC for each thread where each background thread merges saved changes into the main MOC